# Running out of memory, need alternatives

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm trying to run the following piece of code:

```
start_time = time.time()
csvWriter = ModalitySessions.pivot(index='session_id', columns='context_eid', values='name')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

which gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

I found a similar problem online and it seemed like it may be an underlying memory issue. So I tried running the same code on a subset of the data, and it is indeed, a memory issue. Here's the updated code:

```
start_time = time.time()
csvWriter = ModalitySessions.iloc[:2000000].pivot(index='session_id', columns='context_eid', values='name')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This gives me a `MemoryError`.

Would anyone have any idea on how to fix this? I'm dealing with ~3.5 Million sessions and the pivot should return about 900 columns.

Comment: What the heck is `ModalitySessions`?

Comment: Sometimes the easy solution is simply to run it in a high memory environment, such as DigitalOcean's high memory VPS droplets: https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/#droplet
There are always hardware limitations for massive computations. I've written genetic algorithms in C that, despite optimization, still required high memory environments.

Answer (score 1):

You can just break up the original data into smaller chunks and append the result of their respective pivoting to another container that you initialize as empty. You would of course need a function that deals with this process of appending the fragments. As in, something that iterates over the elements of the container table that you are constructing, and compares with the elements of the newly pivoted table made up of the chunk that has just been processed, and adds the values if the column fields match. While terribly inefficient (in terms of computation time) (depending on how many chunks you divide your initial table in), I think it would word around your problem, since you would be dealing with smaller chunks of data at a time, since that appears to be some kind of wraparound error.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method out. I was also wondering if I could replace session_id, 'context_eid` and name by shortint (basically create 3 mappings and store it elsewhere), considering that string datatype will take much more memory as compared to shortint or something.. Would you happen to have any experience with that? Any general comments on whether or not it sounds like a decent idea?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. The new datatypes would, in theory, occupy less of memory. Do check the value range for a short. But do take into account that you will have to iterate the whole table atleast once before times, and, depending of the implementation of the hashmap, you may need to compare the elements of each row with the whole of the hash map you are constructing. Essentially, you are dealing in practice with a dillema that comes up sometimes in computing: you have space complexity (huge amount of memory needed) or time complexity (huge amount of time).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Who cares about grammar when the message come across clearly? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a Python [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to return chunks of the CSV data at a time. In fact, this is why such a tool exists in Python. The generator could then be used to restrict the nubmer of rows loaded in to memory at any time.

Either that or, as I mentioned in my comment, look into a [high memory VPS](http://digitalocean.com/pricing/#droplet).

Comment: Thanks, I will try the generator out. I was also wondering if I could replace `session_id`, 'context_eid` and `name` by `shortint` (basically create 3 mappings and store it elsewhere), considering that `string` datatype will take much more memory as compared to `shortint` or something.. Would you happen to have any experience with that? Any general comments on whether or not it sounds like a decent idea?

Comment: If you're running out of memory, moving things to different mappings likely won't solve the problem. You're still storing the same amount of information (perhaps given a few improvements). You're talking orders of magnitude here. A small improvement won't help if you're still over memory limits by 10 times.